# File creation from path error

Tags: java

I am trying to create a new file on my desktop with the path `"Users/username/Desktop/file.txt"` but when I try to compile my code I get an error but if I use `"../../file.txt"` it works fine.

How would I get this to work from the "Users" path?

Comment: share some code and what errors You are encountering? Do not write Your code here in comments rather put update Your Question with code and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add `/` before the path:

> "/Users/username/Desktop/file.txt"

That worked for me